# FullCalendar.js won't display JSON events from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

My ASP.NET application produces events and, for now, simply stores them in an HTML list, like so:

```
<ul id="eventsList">
  <li>
    {editable:false,id:1,title:"Demo",start:"2018-03-14T00:00:00"}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I convert this list into an array using javascript, like so:

```
var events = [];

$("#eventsList").find('li').each(function () {
  events.push(this.innerText);
});

$('#eventCalendar').fullCalendar({
  height: "parent",
  events: events
});
```

FullCalendar, however, does not display any events - despite the event being in an array as described here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array

What am I missing here?

Comment: That's because your array is just a list of strings (which happens to contain some stuff which looks like JSON), not actual JavaScript objects with individual properties. JSON is a text format, it's not a JS object till you deserialise it.

Comment: Instead, get your application to render the JSON directly into the Javascript (so that the JS will see it as an object immediately) rather than this convoluted double-hop, or even better, make an ajax endpoint to supply the JSON, so that the calendar can dynamically update the events from the database (e.g. when changes are made, or when the date/time range being displayed changes). See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

Comment: @ADyson So can I assume that by attempting to make things less complicated with a hidden field, I have actually further complicated things? I am leaning towards an AJAX endpoint, although this is something I'll need to learn more about.

Comment: I don't see where there's a hidden field in your code, but yeah the idea with the `<li>` is unnecessary. However you're rendering the JSON into the HTML, just render it into the JS directly instead. But the ajax endpoint is a better solution overall. It's not too hard to setup. Are you using ASP.NET MVC, or WebForms?

Comment: @ADyson Sorry for the late response, I'm using a WebForms project for this. I've seen some material on the subject, but I'm very new to AJAX. I'm seeing some material on WCF as well, should I be thinking about using this?

Comment: You can create either a WebMethod, or a little WCF webservice within your WebForms application. WebMethod is probably a little bit simpler if you haven't done it before. Avoid examples using ASMX services - ASMX is basically legacy tech now.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, that's actually very helpful. I'll look at moving towards a WebMethod, and in the meantime get this working per the other answer here whilst I have a little practice.

Comment: you don't need all the guff in that other answer. Like I said, just move the code which generates your JSON from inside the `<li>` to just to the right of `events:` in your script, and you shoud be good to go.

Comment: @ADyson In this case, I'm using Newtonsoft's JSON classes for .NET, which is in C# and thus cannot be implemented in the client-side javascript. However, I did notice that the issue was actually in how I was parsing the JSON - I was using the deprecated `parseJSON()` method rather than `JSON.parse`.

I did remove the `string.replace()` though, since I can output the appropriate JSON string with C#.

Comment: Yes I realise that but how are you putting that JSON into the `<li>`? That must be done via C# code of some kind. You can do the same but injecting it into the Javascript instead of the HTML. It makes no difference really - you're just using the C# to generate some part of the final page. Whether that part is HTML, CSS, Javascript or whatever is not very important.

Comment: e.g. it could be something like `events: <% JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourJSONObject) %>;` or something, depends how you've done it. But that's what I'm getting at.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you push the event data using `innerText`, like this:

```
$("#eventsList").find('li').each(function () {
  events.push(this.innerText);
});
```

It's actually pushing a `string` and not an `object` of an event expected by Fullcalendar.

To get around this, you can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function to parse a JSON string into an object. But the problem is, from your explanation above, the event data within the `<li>` tag is not properly quoted.

```
{editable:false,id:1,title:"Demo",start:"2018-03-14T00:00:00"}
```

To be a valid JSON string, the property name like `editable`, `id`, `title` and `start`, must be properly quoted. To get around this, you can use `replace` and some regex to put the quotes around the property name:

```
var properJSONString = eventString.replace(/([a-z]+):/g, '"$1":')
```

So, to wrap this up you can push the events from the `<li>` tag like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var events = [];

  // Loop through each list.
  $("#eventsList li").each(function () {
    // Get the event data, which is a string.
    var eventString = $(this).text().trim();
    // Properly quote the key (property name), so it's a valid JSON string.
    var jsonString = eventString.replace(/([a-z]+):/g, '"$1":');

    // Parse it to object with JSON.parse() and push it to events variable.
    events.push(JSON.parse(jsonString));
  });

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: "parent",
    events: events
  });
});
```

You may check the demo here: [hopeful-franklin-085848.bitballoon.com](http://hopeful-franklin-085848.bitballoon.com/)

However, it's not a clean solution. FullCalendar already offers a feature to load events directly from your server. Read more about it here: [events (as JSON Feed)](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed).

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: or you could just inject the JSON string directly into the Javascript, and save all that code. Whatever code is used to place it into the `<li>` can be moved to place it directly into the `events` property in the Javascript.

Comment: And your fullcalendar docs URL is wrong - that's the link for declaring Resources in the Scheduler product, nothing to do with events.

Comment: @ADyson Oh yeah, thanks! Fixed the references to the doc.

Comment: @RisanBagjaPradana The thing is, that's actually how JsonConvert (from my C# backend) normally outputs the string. In the documentation for FullCalendar, I noticed something about the variable `editable` being required to have it's value unquoted, which was why I tried using a JsonSerializer object (again in C#) to output the "JSON" you see in my question. 

Could it be that the magic is in your usage of `text().trim()`?

Incidentally, I will be moving to an AJAX solution as per yours and ADyson's suggestion, but I'd like to make this work in the meantime.

Comment: @ScarySpice " I noticed something about the variable editable being required to have it's value unquoted"...Risan is not talking about the value, he's talking about the field names. To be strictly valid JSON, the field names must be quoted e.g. `"editable": false`. But TBH most browsers (and other JSON parsers) will let you get away with it. You're right that the _value_ of `editable` should be unquoted, because it's a boolean field, not a string. Any value in quotes is treated as a string, instead of (for example) a number or a boolean.